# Why is operator[] defined for const std::vector, but not for const std::map?

Tags: c++, stdvector, language-design, stdmap, std

Having this code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void foo1(const std::map<std::string, int> &m)
{
    m["abcd"];
}

void foo2(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &v)
{
    v[0];
}
```

gives only error for `foo1`, but not for `foo2`. As I understand `map` -> it has 2 arrays - one for keys and the second for values. And I understand a `const map` gives me `const int` as value. But so should `vector<vector<int>>`, because accessing element via `[]` is also `const vector<int>`, but is permitted. Moreover, accessing a value via `[]` does not immediately mean I want to `write` a data. I can just read that value, so why even `const map` does not have `operator[]`? (when the compiler does not know If I want to write or read).

#### Edit

The question is for the language design, not standard quotation. As in comments -> you need 1 operator to write in map `operator[]`. But needs 2 operators for vector write `operator[]`, `operator=`. Why does `map::operator[]` automatically expect I want to write? (And therefor create new elements by the provided key)? I can the same as in vector be just trying to read from that map and if that key(pair) does not exists, it can give error or warning, but there is no need to immediately create it.

Comment: "_Moreover, accessing a value via `[]` does not immediately mean I want to `write` a data._" In case of `std::map` : it does, as documentation of [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) states: "_Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist_"

Comment: But so should create new `vector<int>` in case of `v[0]` or?

Comment: `operator[]` of `std::vector` doesn't insert elements. it merely accesses them. If you access it out of bounds, you, merely, invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius does not make sense then when in one case it `write`s but the second it "only" `read`s

Comment: What you believe makes sense, or not is irrelevant. What is relevant is how the required behavior is described in C++ standard (which is what is reflected in cppreference). And this is how it is defined.

Comment: Do you actually want quotes from the standard, or will cppreference do? The language-lawyer tag seems unnecessary.

Comment: @cigien no, I do not need standard quotes, I can read as well as you do. I want to description from language perspective (design), why you can have just one operator for writing in `map` -> `operator[]`, but needs 2 for `write` in `vector` -> `operator[]`, `operator=`. The lawer is needed for this description

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (If I understand, you're asking why `[]` doesn't behave the same way for `vector` and `map`). But your question says "what does compiler thinks about in this scenerio" The compiler is just following the language rules. Maybe you could rephrase the question to ask why the langauge design is like this?

Comment: @cigien editted

Comment: Language design. compiler construction and language lawyering are three *very* different professions.

Comment: I agree with @n.'pronouns'm. Edited tags accordingly.

Comment: This kind of language design questions do not tend to admit authoritative answers. Language design is in large part about giving programmers tools they would like to use. The language is made this way because the designers liked it this way and felt other programmers will too. What people like is subjective. What you like is not what I like is not what everyone else likes. It's a matter of personal taste and opinion. Your question is therefore opinion-based.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. not truly. asking why [] doesn't behave the same way for vector and map is not only about opinion, but also about the decision made. Operators are something programmers have in their head without thinking (more the say functions), so this decision was not small. The question is thus approriate for languge design.

Comment: They don't behave the same way because people like it this way. Language designers could have made any decision. They have made a decision that they felt most people will like. A different decision would make the language less convenient to use. Not wrong, not illogical, just less convenient. There is nothing more than that to it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you still forget that both structure are containers. One is associative and the other one is indexable but have a lot in common. So there is no need to have different semantics about operators (exception of values/types, but not in perspective of the structure). Yet it does.So the reason is not only "for convenience" but it has also a *logical* (of the structure design) reason. I want to know that. Not opinions

Answer (score 5):

This is because `std::map::operator[]` inserts into the map if the referenced element is not present.  The method therefore cannot be declared `const` and therefore cannot be invoked on a `const` object.

Comment: And in case of `v[0]` it does not create new object `vector<int>`? The same rules apply here and is permitted

Comment: _And in case of v[0] it does not create new object vector<int>?_ That is correct.  `v[0]` just returns the zeroth element in `v`, no inserting or assigning takes place.  There is, however, a non-const overload of `std::vector::operator[]` that lets you write things like `v[0] = 42;`

Comment: no, to `write` includes 2 operations in `vector` -> `operator[]`, `operator=`, not just one as in `map` -> `operator[]` is sufficient to `write`. This is what does not make sense from language perspective

Comment: `std::vector::operator[]` and `std::vector::operator=` are fundamentally different.  The first accesses (or writes to) an individual element whereas the second copies the entire vector.